# PostgreSQL 14.2 semicolon on query got error unterminated quoted string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I got issues that cannot resolve, I have sql query that when add semicolon its error.
here my query:

```
INSERT INTO engine_migrations ("name", "description", "schema", "created_at", "up", "down", "active")
VALUES (
    'Create Table users',
    'undefined',
    '{"resource":"Table","migration":{"name":"users","primaryKey":"SERIAL"},"operation":"Create"}',
    '2023-08-18T09:40:49.55656Z',
    '',
    'DELETE FROM "public"."engine_tables" WHERE name = ''users'';DROP TABLE "public"."users";',
    true
);
```

return like this

```
`unterminated quoted string at or near "'delete from "public."engine_tables" where name = ''users''"
```

this is what I found.
when remove `;DROP TABLE "public"."users";` its working fine. but I cannot remove it since required.

Comment: Cannot reproduce (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fkQ1dzpZgnoNF8stEyGJx3/1).  The problem would seem to be on your client side, which you haven't specified, or in some other part of the code you haven't shown.

Comment: @jjanes yeah its to difficult. gonna skip this. thanks